# Struct alignment with bit-fields

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Why is `sizeof(A)` 12?

It should be: `float(4) + x_0-pad(2) + y_1(2) = 8`

If it's aligned all to `float`, how can I avoid this?

```
struct A
{
    int x_0 : 1;
    int x_1 : 1;
    int x_2 : 1;
    int x_3 : 2;
    int x_4 : 2;
    int x_5 : 2;
    int x_6 : 3;
    uint16_t pad : 4;
    uint16_t y_1;
    float y_2;
};
```

Comment: Because the `int` bit-fields are in one storage unit (and its size is probably `sizeof(int)` aka 4), the `uint16_t` bit-field is in another (and its size is probably 2), and the `float` is in another (its size is probably 4), and there's probably 2 bytes of padding between `y_1` and `y_2` for alignment.  Use the same type for all the bit-field members.

Comment: Try changing the types of the x_n fields to `uint16_t`.

Comment: ok, I understand. What should I do with uint16_t bit-field in case if I have enums instead of int?

Comment: Layout of bit-fields is up to the compiler. You can either find documentation for what your compiler does or you can try random things and hope to get what you want. In particular, there is no requirement that those `x_` variables are packed together and take up exactly 12 bits.

Comment: Check if your compiler has a `#pragma pack 1` or `attibute` meta to pack your data without aligning (pack 1). Check also that it allows the field types you need (before C23 fewer types are allowed).

Comment: Using bitwise operations on an `unsigned int` are more portable and standard than using bitfields.

Comment: `sizeof(A)` is not valid C.  C tag removed.

Comment: Bitfields are the source of much misery and confusion. Avoid if you can.

Comment: @Frankie_C C++ has standard [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) since C++11

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ops. I was answering for C language not C++.... My wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit fields don't have a storage but they have memory location of same size as the scalar type you had supplied, therefore alignment usually is at least of same size, but order in a struct is not defined until a zero-sized field is encountered - "non-zero bit-field sequence of same type".

In your case , on little-endian system  your struct is *likely* either oranized like

```
<32bit location #0> x_6 x_5 x_4 x_3 x_2 x_1 x_0 ... 
<16bit location #1> pad ...    
uint16_t      y_1;   
float         y_2;
```

or it can separate bytes (to not break up fields across byte borders)

```
<8bit location #0> x_4 x_3 x_2 x_1 x_0 ...
<8bit location #1> x_6 x_5 ... 
<an optional 16bit padding>
<16bit location #2> pad ...
uint16_t      y_1;
float         y_2;
```

Most modern compiler use first method and it's guaranteed that non-zero fields fill as much of related location as possible. That's why you got  size of 12 bytes: an `int` (4) + 2 `uint16_t`(2) + `float`(4).

*Note: you also can encounter a compiler where an `int` is 16 bit and then it would work as you did expect.*

On big-endian or some flexible architectures it can be

```
<32bit location #0> ... x_0 x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 
<16bit location #1> ... pad
uint16_t      y_1;
float         y_2;
```

A different type causes new location to be considered. You can add a zero-sized field:

```
int x_break: 0;
```

anywhere to break-up the sequence and enforce partial-ordering. Unused bits marked by `...` are not considered padding formally, but work similar.

Unless aligment requrement on `struct` is altered by user, there can be padding before/after `<location #2> pad` to meet aligment requirements of `int`.

***Note** : You cannot even guarantee that bit-fields are starting at begining of struct anymore, only that the general order in relation with other struct's members is preserved.*

***Note 2** : I wrote "likely" because it's up to implementation of compiler to decide how to pack bits, but it is more or less common way to do so.  It's usually same for compilers on same platform fo inter-opearability purposes, but exceptions do exist.*